# Should i continue clearing the screen with the os module or use subprocess?

Tags: python, python-2.7

So, my question is whether i should use the `os.system('cls')` for clearing command line output in a python command line program. I usually use the `os` module way, however, i have read that using the subprocess modules are a better choice for doing calls to the command line. In general, which should i use? And if i do use the subprocess way, how would i go about doing it, as i have very little experience with the module, even though i have tried reading the doc's. Thank you in advance for your replies.

Comment: Have you looked at the subprocess doc? It has abundant examples for replacing all of the other methods for running commands

Comment: yes i have, however, i am confused on how to use `Popopen` and when to use it, how its I/O works ect.

Comment: For something this trivial it doesn't really matter. The subprocess module comes in handy when you need to work with the stdin/stdout/stderr of your child process.

Comment: clearing someones console is a bad thing (especially on linux), better use `urwid` or `curses` if you wanna do fancy stuff with the console.

Comment: Am I the only one wondering why a CLI program would need to clear the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the `subprocess` module to invoke `cls` instead of `os.system()`, just:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("cls", shell=True)
```

If you want something more complex see the [*subprocess* documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html).